# What is the best way to get count of an action and increment

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

I am writing an automated test to where I perform an action recursively , say count a popup window after a click on a button . I need to count how many times I have performed the popup appeared after the click. What is the best way to do it in webdriverio?

```
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i += 1) {
  if (!click) {
     //Perform an action and get count
  }
  else do something
}
```

What is the best way to count an action ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Why must it be inside that for loop? Are you just trying to count how many times you've performed an action like a button click?

Comment: Do the [webdriver.io docs on `click`](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/click.html) not help you out? What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to write a webdriver e2e automated test where I need to count a particular popup after click. I just realized my question wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

To count how many times you've done something like click a button just do something like this:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button> 

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var count = 0;
function myFunction(){
count = count + 1;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
"Count: " + count;
}
</script>
```

Although from your question I'm not exactly sure if this is what you are looking for. If this doesn't answer your question let me know and I'll try to help.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to write a webdriver e2e automated test where I need to count a particular popup after click. I just realized my question wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
<script>
var counter = 0;
function GetCount() {
         counter++;
         document.getElementById("CountText").innerHTML = "Counter = " + counter;
}
</script>

<span id="CountText">0</span>
<button onclick="GetCount();">Click to Increase Counter</button>
```